# Populate a cell in SSRS report by testing value conditions from other column value

Tags: reporting-services

Populate a cell in SSRS report by testing value conditions from other column values

I have 3 columns (category, Month, Amount) in my dataset, with values similar to these below:

```
Category   Month   Amount
A          Jan       20
A          Feb       25
A          Mar       10
R          Jan       15
R          Feb       50
R          Mar       55
```

On the report I need:

```
    Jan   Feb   Mar
A   20    25    10
R   15    50    55
```

I have tried placing this expression in each group row column, for example, in the "Feb" column it would be:

```
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "A" and Fields!Month.Value = "Feb", Fields!Amount.Value, 13)
```

Using IIF, which does not short-circuit, is not evaluating the conditions properly. The "Month" value being a string, it displays always the first row found for the conditions, in this case it would display value 20, instead of 25. If I change the "Month" value to int, it displays the false(13); 
How can I populate my cell correctly, using IIF or something other way?

Any help on this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Alan's answer is the way to go but to make your theory work, you'd want a **Row Group** based on the Category and then SUM to the Amount fields if the month is a match `=SUM(IIF(Fields!Month.Value = "Feb", Fields!Amount.Value, 0))`. Not sure what **13** was for tho.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything like that.

Just use a matrix instead of a table.

Add the matrix to the report, you'll see three placeholder names, (from memory) something like Rows, Column and Data. Drag your Category field to the rows cell, your month field to the columns cell and your Amount field to the data cell. That's it....

The only problem you will have is the columns would be ordered alphabetically by default. It would be better to have the Month number in your dataset too so you can order by that. You set the column order by right-clicking the column group name in the row/column group panel which is under your main report design area.

Comment: For the Month SORT ORDER, you could use: `=MONTH(CDATE(Fields!Month.Value & " 01 " & Today.Year))`.

Comment: 1) '=SUM(IIF(Fields!Month.Value = "Feb", Fields!Amount.Value, 0))' , gives error. (13 just a differentiation from 0, just for testing)

Comment: You don't need any expressions just follow the instructions I gave

Comment: 1) =SUM(IIF(Fields!Month.Value = "Feb", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)), gives error. (13 just a differentiation from 0, just for testing) ;                                  2) Matrix works ;                                                                                    3)@Hannover Fist,  I need to sort the columns based on the date parameter entered to be the prior year month first and increase until the date entered, for the period of 12 months. For example, being the parameter '03/31/2018', it would first display 'Apr 2017', then 'May 2017', ....last column 'Mar 2018'. thanks

Comment: You should post a new question if your original question has been answered.